# Loading Node.js files asynchronously

Tags: node.js, npm

I want to load 100+ JS files at once from a directory.

Instead of doing:

```
const results = files.map(f => require(f));
```

I'd like to do something like:

```
async.map(files, function(f, cb){

   fs.readFile(f, function(err, data){
       // this require() call won't work, but you get the idea
       cb(null, require(data);  
   });

}, function(err, results){

});
```

Is this `require-from-string` module the best bet to do this?
https://www.npmjs.com/package/require-from-string

one **problem** is that I don't think the require cache will be set for these files, and that is sort of a problem.

Is there a way to manually set the `require.cache` value?

Comment: I opened a related issue on Github for the `require-from-string` package - https://github.com/floatdrop/require-from-string/issues/13

Comment: What’s the logic for doing this asynchronously? Do you want to avoid the loading time, or the processing time? Also the files yiu’ Loading may in turn load other files, which may defeat what you’re trying to achieve.

Comment: @jcaron that's true, if the 100 files actually load shared files, I am not sure how that would work. And yes, very possible that many of the 100 files would be loading shared paths.

Comment: but yeah the motivation is only to reduce loading time, not sure how much difference it would make.

Comment: I think we would need more details about your specific use case before anyone could give any kind of good answer.

Comment: This does seem to be a case of the "tail wagging the dog" here. You seem to be jumping though hoops to "make your code load faster" when the usual and common practice here is to employ a "build process" that does that. So "at a glace" what you appear to actually need is a build process which "bundles" your application, and "possibly" augments that with some "on demand loading" of additional features after startup. But it's likely this "parallel require" essentially breaks down to *" .. not the droids you are looking for ..."*. So either needs more detail or looking in the wrong place.

Comment: @NeilLunn this is for a command line library, not for an application, so build process won't help in this case. The files are the end-user's files, not the library files, so I cannot pre-load them. If that makes sense.

Comment: @AlexanderMills I think you presume to much that you are "not understood". So to "correct you" your "command line library" can be **built**, just like anything else. It's perfectly valid to "rollup" and "build" your node code for a general deployment. And since the particular requirement here is *"avoid loading time of all these `require` statements"*, then even if you don't realize that's is what you are asking, then it actually IS what you are asking. Hence "tail wagging the dog".

Comment: No you werent listening to me. Read what I wrote again :)

Comment: The part with the end users files :)

Comment: To make it clear - I cannot easily pre-package end users files in a library. It's simply not an easy general solution. Packaging a whole application including libraries usually takes significant effort on the end user's part.